# gollvm: Why does gollvm only support X86_64_SysV and ARM_AAPCS

Tags: go

I found that gollvm only supports llvm::CallingConv::X86_64_SysV, llvm::CallingConv::ARM_AAPCS, but llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/CallingConv.h has many types of calling conventions(eg: C, Fast, X86_VectorCall, ARM_AAPCS_VFP.......)，
do other types need support?

I just want to port of gollvm for RISCV, but I don't know what type of calling conversion to choose